# Script take input from stdin and navigate to a website and return output

Tags: html, ruby, xpath

I am a Ruby on Rails developer who has been asked to write a pure Ruby script.

The goal is to:

1. Take user input using stdin
2. Navigate to a URL
3. Fill out a form using the stdin input
4. Submit the form and navigate to a search result page
5. Return output to the stdout based on the results

I have never done anything like this in pure Ruby, as most of my experience is with Rails, and would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am familiar with xpath and my gut is to use it in some fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gets` for std input. To connect to a server you could do something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse gets.chomp
http = Net::HTTP.start url.host
request_params = '?foo=bar'
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new url.path + request_params
response = http.request request
puts response.body
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am sorry what part of the scrip represents the input paramater that goes into the form

Comment: And why waste time with Net::HTTP when Open::URI will do as good or better?

Comment: `gets` get's a string from stdin the chomp part removes the trailing crlf. I used Net::HTTP because he said he wants to fill out forms. as far as i know, you can't POST with open-uri (can you?)

Answer (score 2):

[Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) is your friend. It makes it easy to navigate sites, fill in forms and submit them, and is the standard for Ruby.

From the guide:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://google.com/')

# point to the form
google_form = page.form('f')

# fill in a field
google_form.q = 'ruby mechanize'

# submit the form
page = agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)

# page will now contain the returned search results
```

Check out the [guide](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/GUIDE.rdoc) and the [examples](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/tree/master/examples) for more information.

Mechanize is built on top of [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), which is the predominate XML/HTML parser for Ruby, so if you need to search the document's DOM in a manner not directly supported by Mechanize, you can easily do it. Nokogiri supports CSS accessors in addition to XPath, making it easy to leverage your HTML and CSS coding knowledge.

Comment: I am new to this sort of thing. How do I install mechanize on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to submit the form using HTTP requests. Use a http library like [faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday)